# Sed deletion affecting all lines in file

Tags: bash, git, sed, pom.xml

*Disclaimer: I have very little experience with sed.*

I'm trying to automate a somewhat tedious task by use of a bash script, and one of the steps is to remove a single line from a Maven pom.xml file, which I'm trying to do with the following sed command:

```
sed -i '/<module>'"${MODULE_NAME}"'<\/module>/d' ./pom.xml
```

It seems to work fine. The problem is that all lines of the pom are affected by this, as a `git diff`call shows that 1,680 lines have been added and 1,681 lines have been removed.

This is obviously a pain, as it makes it very hard for code reviewers to spot the one line difference.Is there a way to make sed perform this deletion without it affecting the other lines in the file?

**EDIT:** When opening the project in IntelliJ, the diff is correctly recognized as just a single line. In addition it seems that sed has changed line break style from CRLF to LF (yes, I'm on Windows). Would this be enough to trigger all lines to be different in git?

Comment: Can you paste the file, that you want to modify?

Comment: Sorry, no. It's confidential, but the structure is like this:
`<project><modules><module>MODULE_NAME</module></modules></project>`

Comment: I am rather interested if 1680 lines affected are only `<module>` lines or maybe problem is caused because you are using Windows and somehow line endings were changed by your script or you have git misconfigured regarding line endings, etc.

Comment: Not related to `sed` in any way. It's a Git issue.

Comment: Was it not `sed` that altered the line endings in the file? Or do you mean that it's a Git issue that different line endings are seen by Git as a difference in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ git diff --ignore-space-at-eol
```

*edit*

To avoid unintended line change, you can configure Git to automatically change line endings using [core.autocrlf](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) or use `unix2dos` program to fix file after `sed`.

Comment: This does it locally! It was obviously a line ending issue. That being said, the file still shows up in the remote repository as having a 1680 lines diff after committing, as the remote file has CRLF line endings as well. As of now my dirty quick fix is to perform this command after replacing the line: `sed -i 's/$'"/`echo \\\r`/" ./pom.xml` to revert to CRLF line endings before committing. I would love suggestions to improve it.

Comment: To convert files between unix and dos encodings you don't need sed, use following programs: `dos2unix`, `unix2dos` (I don't know if you have them installed with bash on windows, but they are usually part of any Linux distribution). You can force Git to specific behaviour regarding line endings using `core.autocrlf` config option (but it's tricky).

Comment: Great, `unix2dos` worked perfectly (in bash on Windows)! If you add it to your answer, I'll accept it.